# "the 18 generations of Hung kings” or "18 Hung King’s dynasties"

Tags: word-choice

> The Bronze Age, and the Van Lang - Au Lac period (around the year 3000 to the end of the 1st millennium BC) imprinted the dawn of founding and defending the country of **18 Hung King’s dynasties**. This period boldly marks the genesis of Vietnamese history and culture.

Which phrase should I use here?

Comment: What does "*defend the country **of*** dynasties" mean? Are these Vietnamese dynasties defending the country, or are they foreign, and the country is defending itself against them? Or are you identifying the country as "the country of 18 dynasties"?

Comment: A dynasty isn't the same thing as a generation. Look them up in a dictionary.

Comment: Hint: a *dynasty* has multiple generations. Also, what do you mean by "imprinted "?